# Is bumping old freya-related questions an intended behavior?

Tags: discussion

We know that the system bumps questions as active so that unanswered questions might get attention again. But [questions like this](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/7162/problem-installing-elementary-os-freya) might not deserve the bump as it is for Freya, an older version we have way long ago. Installation/driver problems are probably solved on the later elementary/Ubuntu release.

Is this really an intended behavior?

Comment: I don't think we have many new questions, so I guess the painful answer is to answer them and get at least one up-vote for the answer. I mean the cheeky answer is "the problem is fixed in Loki+, consider upgrading your OS to the current version" That could warrant an upvote - then it wouldn't keep getting bumped.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The system doesn't care.

The criteria for bumping are:

> posts eligible for bumping are those scoring >= 0 that have gone at least 30 days with no activity, have at least one non-deleted answer scoring 0 and none scoring more than that, and no accepted answer (also, they can't be locked or closed).
>   <sub>[-@Shog9](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184485/community-seems-to-be-bumping-new-questions-more-frequently-than-usual/184511#184511)</sub>

The system doesn't care if it's an old version.

Answer (score 0):

I still love Freya and I can give you a good reason to keep the old posts. Consider Windows 95 and 98 - the fat32 format is still a stable and universal way to transfer between different operating systems. We use it on our pen drives.
I had my first PC in 1997 and I literally tore it's insides out and went through agony to understand how it worked. When I eventually did some Microsoft training I felt the benefit.
Freya has a lot of stability and is versatile and clean. It's always worth learning the basics of anything before moving onto the more complex variations.